# hidden_field syntax problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field

I have been trying to pass what round the users intends to go to by which button they click through a hidden field that passes in the round number.

```
<%= form_for @round, :url => { :action => 'pick_page'} do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :round, :value => '1', :class =>'round1' %>
<%= f.submit 'Picks', :class => 'round1' %>

<%= f.hidden_field :round, :value => '2', :class =>'round2' %>
<%= f.submit 'Picks', :class => 'round2' %>

<% end %>
```

With this code I constantly get 2 passed through as the round in my pick_page. It is obviously skipping over the first hidden field. How can I get it so 'f.submit' submits the round number that is associated with its class.

Comment: You should use 2 different forms I think

Answer (score 1):

We just had the same problem! We fixed it creating 2 diferent forms right next to each other.

```
<%= form_for @round, :url => { :action => 'pick_page'} do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :round, :value => '1', :class =>'round1' %>
<%= f.submit 'Picks', :class => 'round1' %>

<%= f.hidden_field :round, :value => '2', :class =>'round2' %>
<%= f.submit 'Picks', :class => 'round2' %>

<% end %>
```

Change it to

```
<%= form_for @round, :url => { :action => 'pick_page'} do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :round, :value => '1', :class =>'round1' %>
<%= f.submit 'Picks', :class => 'round1' %>

<% end %>

<%= form_for @round, :url => { :action => 'pick_page'} do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :round, :value => '2', :class =>'round2' %>
<%= f.submit 'Picks', :class => 'round2' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the hidden fields and add a `name` and `value` attributes on your submit button.

Comment: adding a value field like
   :value => '1'
makes the name of the button '1'

Comment: Sorry, did not think of that. Then you can give them different name, not use value, and check if a params of this name is sent ? I do not see other solution without using JS.